# Clear a datastore and repopulate it

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have the following store:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.store.AdultMenuStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    onItemDisclosure: true,
    model:'Sencha.model.MenuPoint',
    data: [
        {
            id:   'addChild',
            name: 'Add child',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-plussign.png',
            xtype: 'addchildform'
        },{
            id:   'share',
            name: 'Share',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-shareicon.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        },{
            id:   'myProfile',
            name: 'My Profile',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-profile.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        },{
            id:   'help',
            name: 'Help',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-question.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        }]
}
});
```

Which uses the following model:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.model.MenuPoint', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'icon_url', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'xtype', type: 'string'}
    ]
}
});
```

Some places in the code I add menu points dynamically like this:

```
 var child = children[i];
 var menuPoint = Ext.create('Sencha.model.MenuPoint', {id: child.childId, name: child.firstName, icon_url: 'aLink', xtype: 'childmenu'});
 store.add(menuPoint);
```

And sometimes I need to clear the store, ergo remove the menu points I added dynamically and only use the menu points I hardcoded in the store. I see methods for removing and adding in the store, but I dont know how to reset the store and repopulate it with the static data I defined there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do as I have answered on your prev question, which you did not respect :)

```
var data = [
        {
            id:   'addChild',
            name: 'Add child',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-plussign.png',
            xtype: 'addchildform'
        },{
            id:   'share',
            name: 'Share',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-shareicon.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        },{
            id:   'myProfile',
            name: 'My Profile',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-profile.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        },{
            id:   'help',
            name: 'Help',
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-question.png',
            xtype: 'childmenu'
        }]

store.load(function (store) {
    store.add(data)// data is an array with you local data
})
```

store.load() function cleans up prev data

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: yet again Thanks Oleg, you save my day over and over again ))